# How to read youtube data api v3 response in php

Tags: json, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have following code:

```
$yt_profiles = $youtube->channels->listChannels('brandingSettings', array(
'mine' => 'true',
));
```

That returns the following output:

```
Google_Service_YouTube_ChannelListResponse Object
(
[collection_key:protected] => items
[etag] => "WFPuK6TsnblcGPcnMex79s42ynQ/sTnuE1bHO-tokx_mFFDt1ybN90g"
[eventId] => 
[itemsType:protected] => Google_Service_YouTube_Channel
[itemsDataType:protected] => array
[kind] => youtube#channelListResponse
[nextPageToken] => 
[pageInfoType:protected] => Google_Service_YouTube_PageInfo
[pageInfoDataType:protected] => 
[prevPageToken] => 
[tokenPaginationType:protected] => Google_Service_YouTube_TokenPagination
[tokenPaginationDataType:protected] => 
[visitorId] => 
[modelData:protected] => Array
    (
        [pageInfo] => Array
            (
                [totalResults] => 1
                [resultsPerPage] => 1
            )

        [items] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [kind] => youtube#channel
                        [etag] => "WFPuK6TsnblcGPcnMex79s42ynQ/ecOcHFmWyWQ7ToCD7-B1L36b4L4"
                        [id] => UCQO6uXy5maTpYvSa_yM--Bw
                        [brandingSettings] => Array
                            (
                                [channel] => Array
                                    (
                                        [title] => Vasim Padhiyar
                                        [showRelatedChannels] => 1
                                        [featuredChannelsTitle] => Featured Channels
                                        [featuredChannelsUrls] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => UCw-TnDmYDQyjnZ5qpVWUsSA
                                            )

                                        [profileColor] => #000000
                                    )

                                [image] => Array
                                    (
                                        [bannerImageUrl] => http://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/channels/c4/default_banner-vfl7DRgTn.png
                                    )

                                [hints] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [property] => channel.featured_tab.template.string
                                                [value] => Everything
                                            )

                                        [1] => Array
                                            (
                                                [property] => channel.banner.image_height.int
                                                [value] => 0
                                            )

                                        [2] => Array
                                            (
                                                [property] => channel.modules.show_comments.bool
                                                [value] => True
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[processed:protected] => Array
    (
    )
```

)

I want to loop through modelData:protected variable to get the list of channels and its items data. Its json object so $yt_profiles->modelData:protected not working while accessing. Please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can reach it as in an array:

```
print_r ($yt_profiles['modelData']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your request:

```
$yt_profiles = $youtube->channels->listChannels('brandingSettings', array(
'mine' => 'true',
));
```

To acces to values **Channel title** for example:

```
$titleChannel = $yt_profiles["items"][0]["brandingSettings"]["channel"]["title"];
```

To acces to values **bannerImageUrl** for example:

```
$banner = $yt_profiles["items"][0]["brandingSettings"]["image"]["bannerImageUrl"];
```

Comment: My question was to create loop. Your code isn't dynamic. What if i have more than 1 channel ? I want to replace [0] with dynamic loop variable $i. example: for($i=0; $i<total_channels; $i++)

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you?

```
    $yt_profiles = $youtube->channels->listChannels('id, brandingSettings', array('mine' => 'true',));

    foreach ($yt_profiles['modelData']['items'] as $searchResult) {
      switch ($searchResult['kind']) {
        case 'youtube#channel':
          $channels[]= array('id'=> $searchResult['id'],
                             'brandingSettings'=> $searchResult['brandingSettings']);
          break;
      }
    }
```